# Nodejs - how compile bson parser?

Tags: node.js, bson

Every time I try to do anything in Nodejs, what is connected with mangodb or sockets, then I receive error:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Native bson parser not compiled, please compile or avoid using native_parser=true
```

what should I compile, use, install, etc to avoid it?
I was trying install mangodb, node-mongodb-native also during node-mongodb-native installation I get message:

```
 cxx: bson.cc -> build/default/bson_1.o
```

so probably I have bson somewhere...

I am using:
node 0.4.7
Ubuntu 10.10

EDIT.
What I am trying to run:

1. I downloaded github.com/pubsubio/chat
2. Installed packaged for this project are:

> ```
> /home/mrok/nodejs/pubsub/pubsubio-chat
> ├── bson@0.0.3 
> ├── common@0.1.1 
> ├── galletita@0.1.1 
> ├── mongodb@0.9.6-7 
> ├─┬ mongojs@0.1.6 
> │ ├── common@0.1.1 
> │ └── mongodb@0.9.6-7 
> ├─┬ mongoose@1.7.3 
> │ ├── colors@0.5.0 
> │ └── hooks@0.1.9 
> ├─┬ pubsub.io@0.1.7 
> │ └── json-sockets@0.2.0 
> └── router@0.3.1
> ```

and I still receive:

> Native bson parser not compiled, please compile or avoid using
>   native_parser=true

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: updated my answer. I got server.js up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## BEGIN UPDATE

### Install mongodb-native

```
mkdir /tmp/mongodb-native
cd /tmp/mongodb-native
git clone https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native
make
```

### Install mongojs

```
npm install mongojs
```

### END UPDATE

First install [npm](http://npmjs.org/).next I would advice you to  install [mongoose](https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose/) instead. It is very popular mongodb utility library. When you use package manager like npm your dependencies will get installed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for help, unfortunately problem still occurs.

Comment: wow - I did not expect that installing bson can be so easy. Thanks for this.

You helped me a lot, but I still have the same case. I will describe more what I am going to achieve.

1. I downloaded https://github.com/pubsubio/chat

2. Installed packaged for this project are:
/home/mrok/nodejs/pubsub/pubsubio-chat
├── bson@0.0.3 
├── common@0.1.1 
├── galletita@0.1.1 
├── mongodb@0.9.6-7 
├─┬ mongojs@0.1.6 
│ ├── common@0.1.1 
│ └── mongodb@0.9.6-7 
├─┬ mongoose@1.7.3 
│ ├── colors@0.5.0 
│ └── hooks@0.1.9 
├─┬ pubsub.io@0.1.7 
│ └── json-sockets@0.2.0 
└── router@0.3.1

Comment: @mrok the more information you provide the better stackoverflow users can help you.

Comment: Formatting in comment looks bad also comments has length limit. I will update main question.

PS. bison that sounds heavy ;)

Comment: lol you need to install mongojs => `npm install mongojs`. That's all :P

Comment: ok I have solution. I needed to find every node_modules directory which contained mongodb package, removed it and install again by  npm install mongodb --mongodb:native  
Alfred thanks for your tips and advices

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by changing the line 28 of node-mongodb-native/lib/mongodb/db.js file to
this.native_parser = this.options.native_parser = false;

You can also use npm install mongodb --mongodb:native

However, it is not recommended since the native driver works slower than the JavaScript one.

Comment: this worked form me, although it wasnt on line 28, a search for 'this.native_parser' revealed the necessary edit, this will do as a temporary fix so that i can at least play with node and mongo, cheers all